# Is there another word for bipartisan to mean all parties?

Tags: synonyms, politics

I find myself needing to write about a "bipartisan" issue, in a country which, unlike the US, doesn't have two main parties. Would the word thus still be "bi"partisan, or something more akin to "omnipartisan"?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I just don't know.

Thank you.

Comment: Would “nonpartisan” do the trick?

Comment: @Qaz please post that as an answer

Comment: How about *transpartisan*?  I just coined this word, and cannot say if anyone uses it; but it would surely be understood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could consider **cross-party** group or cross-party consensus, depending on the context:

> Cross-party activities involve two or more political parties. A cross-party group consists of members from two or more political parties.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cross-party

Comment: Indeed, we do often use "cross-party" to describe things in the UK: "UK government seeks cross-party talks to tackle social care crisis" https://www.ft.com/content/4aa0299a-5fc9-11ea-b0ab-339c2307bcd4

Comment: I am going to be taking this as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"Multipartisan" is recognized by some, but not all, dictionaries.

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/multipartisan

multipartisan
(also multipartizan)
adjective

```
Of, representing, or composed of members of more than two (political or other) parties.
```

Answer (score 1):

A measure with support from all parties is often called “nonpartisan.” For example, “We’re in political gridlock on partisan issues like X and Y, but at least we can make progress in nonpartisan initiatives like preventing car crashes and pedestrian accidents.”

Merriam Webster:
not partisan, especially : free from party affiliation, bias, or designation